# In Mockito, how can I verify order with a parallel section inside a sequential section?

Tags: java, unit-testing, concurrency, mocking, mockito

I have some code that performs some work in sequence, performs some operations in parallel, and then performs some more work in sequence once the parallel work is complete.  I do not care in which order the parallel work happens, just that it all happens in the middle.  Using Mockito, how can I verify that the parallel work happens in the middle of the sequential work, but without caring about the order of the middle parallel calls?

I know that I can use [InOrder](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/InOrder.html) to verify a strict ordering amongst all the calls, or to exclude some calls from the ordering checks altogether, but this does not quite handle my use case.  Additionally, since we're dealing with concurrent code, it doesn't handle the fact that ideally we'd want to verify that the final sequential methods should only get called after the parallel methods complete, not just after they're called.

```
public interface MockedClass {
    void initialMethodOne();
    void initialMethodTwo();
    void parallelMethodOne();
    void parallelMethodTwo();
    void finalMethodOne();
    void finalMethodTwo();
}
```

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class InOrderExample {
    private MockedClass mockedClass;

    public InOrderExample(MockedClass mockedClass) {
        this.mockedClass = mockedClass;
    }

    public void doOrderedAndParallelWork() {
        mockedClass.initialMethodOne();
        mockedClass.initialMethodTwo();

        CompletableFuture.allOf(
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(mockedClass::parallelMethodOne),
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(mockedClass::parallelMethodTwo))
        .join();

        mockedClass.finalMethodOne();
        mockedClass.finalMethodTwo();
    }
}
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InOrder;

import static org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class InOrderExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void doOrderedAndParallelWork() {
        MockedClass mockedClass = mock(MockedClass.class);

        doAnswer(answersWithDelay(200, invocation -> null)).when(mockedClass).parallelMethodOne();
        doAnswer(answersWithDelay(100, invocation -> null)).when(mockedClass).parallelMethodTwo();

        new InOrderExample(mockedClass).doOrderedAndParallelWork();

        InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockedClass);

        // These two must happen first, in order
        inOrder.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodOne();
        inOrder.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodTwo();

        // Not quite what I want; these two must happen after the first two and before the last two, but I don't want
        // the test to fail if these two are called in opposite order
        inOrder.verify(mockedClass).parallelMethodOne();
        inOrder.verify(mockedClass).parallelMethodTwo();

        // These two must happen last, in order
        inOrder.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodOne();
        inOrder.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodTwo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't see anywhere that it's explicitly called out in [the Mockito documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#6) or elsewhere, experimentation has shown that it is possible to use multiple `InOrder` objects at the same time to verify the same calls.  Once can then then verify each path independently (possibly in a loop if there are more than a couple parallel calls).

```
@Test
public void doOrderedAndParallelWork2() {
    MockedClass mockedClass = mock(MockedClass.class);

    doAnswer(answersWithDelay(200, invocation -> null)).when(mockedClass).parallelMethodOne();
    doAnswer(answersWithDelay(100, invocation -> null)).when(mockedClass).parallelMethodTwo();

    new InOrderExample(mockedClass).doOrderedAndParallelWork();

    // Verify the strictly sequential portion
    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockedClass);
    inOrder.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodOne();
    inOrder.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodTwo();
    inOrder.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodOne();
    inOrder.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodTwo();

    // Verify the first call is executed in the right order relative to the sequential portion
    InOrder inOrder1 = inOrder(mockedClass);
    inOrder1.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodTwo();
    inOrder1.verify(mockedClass).parallelMethodOne();
    inOrder1.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodOne();

    // Verify the second call is executed in the right order relative to the sequential portion
    InOrder inOrder2 = inOrder(mockedClass);
    inOrder2.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodTwo();
    inOrder2.verify(mockedClass).parallelMethodTwo();
    inOrder2.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodOne();
}
```

One thing this does not solve, however, is the requirement that the final methods only get called after the parallel methods complete. Mockito does not appear to have native support for this sort of verification, but we can do the following as a workaround:

```
@Test
public void doOrderedAndParallelWork3() {
    MockedClass mockedClass = mock(MockedClass.class);
    CheckComplete methodOneComplete = mock(CheckComplete.class);
    CheckComplete methodTwoComplete = mock(CheckComplete.class);

    doAnswer(answersWithDelay(200, invocation -> {methodOneComplete.complete(); return null;}))
            .when(mockedClass).parallelMethodOne();
    doAnswer(answersWithDelay(100, invocation -> {methodTwoComplete.complete(); return null;}))
            .when(mockedClass).parallelMethodTwo();

    new InOrderExample(mockedClass).doOrderedAndParallelWork();

    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockedClass, methodOneComplete, methodTwoComplete);
    inOrder.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodOne();
    inOrder.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodTwo();
    inOrder.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodOne();
    inOrder.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodTwo();

    InOrder inOrder1 = inOrder(mockedClass, methodOneComplete);
    inOrder1.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodTwo();
    inOrder1.verify(methodOneComplete).complete();
    inOrder1.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodOne();

    InOrder inOrder2 = inOrder(mockedClass, methodTwoComplete);
    inOrder2.verify(mockedClass).initialMethodTwo();
    inOrder2.verify(methodTwoComplete).complete();
    inOrder2.verify(mockedClass).finalMethodOne();
}

private interface CheckComplete {
    void complete();
}
```